# Getting image size in ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Can I get the height of an image from its URL information in ActionScript 3?

I have the image URL. I want to draw the image in my UI and I want to set the height of the drawing area dynamically upon getting the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the height/width of an image only after loading it to your SWF. Load the image using a `Loader` instance, cast the `loader.content` to `Image`, read the height and width of its `bitmapData`.

Comment: Yeah , i did it and is getting the dimensions correctly, using LoaderInfo. 
Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the loader class.
Once the image is loaded in the object, use `loaderInfo` for getting the image properties.